# My mother is a French citizen through marriage. Can I live in France?

Tags: france, resident-permit, citizenship

My mother has been in France for the past 15 years. I’m an Israeli citizen living in the US as a green card holder.

If I wanted to legally live in France and be with her is there anything that can be done? I’m in my 30s.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you need to be either younger than 21 years or dependent on your mother to qualify for a residence permit as the child of a French citizen.  For example, the relevant [page at service-public.fr includes](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F11168) (emphasis added):

> famille d'un Français (époux d'un Français, parent d'un enfant français mineur vivant en France, enfant **de moins de 21 ans ou à charge** d'un Français, parents, grands-parents ou beaux-parents à charge d'un Français)

Translation:

> family of a French citizen (spouse of a French citizen, parent of a French minor living in France, child **of less than 21 years or dependent** on a French citizen, parents, grandparents or parents in law dependent on a French citizen)

Source: https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F11168

Therefore, the answer to your question:

> If I wanted to legally live in France and be with her is there anything that can be done?

You can use [any of the other routes that are available to everyone](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/N110), whether through work or as an "economically inactive" visitor.